# Type error when using Array.find with a custom type

Tags: typescript

I have an object containing a list of supported languages. I'd like to find the user's browser contains one of the languages:

```js
const userLanguage = browserLanguages.find(language => !!supported[language]);
```

However, I'm getting the following error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'LanguageName' has no index signature.`

`LanguageName` is a type I've created for my `supported` object:

```js
type LanguageName = {
  [language in SupportedLanguages]: string;
};
```

And `supportedLanguages` is a type containing all languages supported by our app:

```js
type SupportedLanguages = 'en' | 'es';
```

**[DEMO](https://repl.it/repls/KookyBlankAnalysts)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll get the best results by explicitly invoking the [overload of `Array.find()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L31) which treats the callback as a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  Note that you have to do this via manual annotation; the compiler does not currently [infer type guards from function return values](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14891).

There are multiple ways to do this; here's one:

```
// make an explicit type guard for SupportedLanguages    
function supportedLanguageGuard<T extends keyof any>(
  x: T
): x is T & SupportedLanguages {
  return !!(supported as any)[x];
}

// use it
const userLanguage: SupportedLanguages | undefined = browserLanguages.find(
  supportedLanguageGuard
); // okay
```

I went this way because it should work whether or not you narrow `browserLanguages` to keep track of the literals inside it

```
const browserLanguages = ["fr", "es"] as const; // TS3.4+
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrmMB7ATsCATAMgQwHYDmcOBEAzlALxQBEEeNUAPreTQNwBQnokUuhYqQByOALbRqAbygBtADb4iJaAEs8sBMjSYBy0mQC6ALihlgKdQSgBfLpwDGSPObNbU6DKb1CIoiVRQUpxQUPSmNACihPKqZAAWNAA0IWFkEZFkYDgAj0jyNJx23E4uwFAARihIAO5kECg+KhTUsjQAZijJrGQ0hvbtcHgOwKrObogeukq+AOLEKBgAPAAqYQAe6HgYFADWECBI7VD4IAB8ABSp66YrnACUputQcVBrAGSakzrYM81BqRQEGAcBQGgAhOCLmR3D8ThRTvdZOt+kUSs5XHB6o0-qRTPBvp4mgZmFAhhgIO11JhAlVatjieQAHRU7ZXUIwwnTQQqeY4RYPeylMj5CBM+RIAgXLENRn3LhAA)